# Rails Generating ave for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5

I have model setup as per below:

> **Father**
>
> has_many :children, through: :another_model
>
> **Children**
>
> has_one :father, :through => :another_model
>
> has_many :grand_children
>
> **Grand_children**
>
> belongs_to :Children

I want to find the average age of Grand_Children for a Father & also generating it for multiple Fathers (and ordering them). There are a lot of possible ages (numbers) in Grand_children so I'm mindful that a query could get pretty large and slow quickly.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to get to (without joins, etc): Father.order('ave(grand_children.age) DESC').

I've looked into a few different ways of doing this with Active Record, but typically examples are only 1 associated model deep.

Any questions, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, I am confused about your relationship. Why `GrandFather` has_many `fathers`?  But you can try this gem https://github.com/khiav223577/deep_pluck

Comment: Can you add the DB schema and an example with some real data of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've reworded / updated the relationship so hopefully they're a little easier to understand and given an example.

Answer (score 1):

With any model you could use, you're looking at a combinatorial explosion. It would be much more efficient to give Grandfather an `average_grandson_age` attribute, and simply update it every time a son is added.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. I've read on previous posts not to do this, but they were for standard first level associations.